# Cant install win10 after Ubuntu 16.04 , gpt error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

i have 16.04 installed. i used ubuntu live cd to allocate a new space by dividing root partition.

i put windows 10 usb, did legacy support option and it could see windows instalation.

then i chose my unallocated part from which gparted did in ubuntu live cd

this image shows before this allocation. devsda2 was divided 500 gb and 400 gb. other one is allocated.

[image]

but windows did no accept to install that drive.

there were 4 drives. 3 of them were like in the picture.

because it says the disk is gpt. cant do.

```
"Windows cannot be installed to this disk. The selected disk is of the GPT partition style".
```

So i make listdisk list part select that partition (it wwas partition 4 there in console but while installing windows screen , there was 3).

i wrote convert mbr inside that prtition but it said cant convert to mbr, only cdroms etc can cause. It was like this. So now i couldnot convert. i cant clean disk because i have ubuntu there.

are thre any ways?

Comment: 4 years ago. maybe newer methods

Comment: Irrelevant. Ubuntu 12.04 is from 4 years ago, and it still has support. You'd be surprised how many "old" methods still work properly.